# Android google smart lock - how to change locale?

Tags: android, google-api, google-smartlockpasswords

I have forked **firebaseUI-auth library** and they are using google smartlock. the issue i am facing is that i change the locale of the application at runtime. i ask the user what locale they want and then i change the locale and the issue is google smart lock prompts do not change. they keep the devices locale. here is how i am changing the locale of each activity:

```
public class Util {
     private static Locale sLocale;

    @NonNull
    public static void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        sLocale = locale;
        if(sLocale != null) {
            Locale.setDefault(sLocale);
        }
    }

    public static void updateConfig(@NonNull ContextThemeWrapper wrapper) {
        if(sLocale != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.setLocale(sLocale);
            wrapper.applyOverrideConfiguration(configuration);
        }
    }
```

and then when the activity is ready to change the locale it does this is its constructor:

```
 public MyActivity() {
        Util.updateConfig(this);
    }
```

and it works fine but not for google smart lock which really is not apart of my application. How can i insert another locale for google smart lock prompts to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Smart Lock dialogs are system prompts and use the system locale by design; they are a separate process and not intended to be part of the application UI.